# R code to separate co-ordinates in a sinle column into two columns of latitude and longitude

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr

I have this data in one column called coordinates.

```
 coordinates                                                                           
  <chr>                                                                         
35.9289842120708,-0.37401629584697;35.9295981311974,-0.370106682789026
```

I would wish to split this into two columns lat and long such that my final output appears like this

```
lat<-c(35.92898,35.92960)
lon<-c(-0.3740163,-0.3701067)
final<-data.frame(lat,lon)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% transmute(id = row_number(), lat = str_extract_all(coordinates, '\\d{2}\\.\\d+'), lon = str_extract_all(coordinates,'-\\d\\.\\d+')) %>% unnest(cols = everything())
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id lat              lon               
  <int> <chr>            <chr>             
1     1 35.9289842120708 -0.37401629584697 
2     1 35.9295981311974 -0.370106682789026
```

Data used:

```
df
                                                             coordinates
1 35.9289842120708,-0.37401629584697;35.9295981311974,-0.370106682789026
```

Comment: This is perfect.suppose i wanted to add another column such that there is an extra column with a common id such that i get the output id<-c(1,1) ;lat<-c(35.92,35.93) ; lon<-c(-0.37,-0.38); df<-data.frame(id,lat,lon).  Thankyou in advance

Comment: @SamMwenda, I've updated my answer, please check if that works for you.

Comment: works perfectly. you make research interesting

Comment: @SamMwenda, thanks, if it works, can you please "accept" the answer